# Текст с большой буквы после точки

Tags: javascript

Как решить такую задачу

```
var str = 'текст. текст. текст'
```

на выходе будет

```
'Текст. Текст. Текст
```

Answer (score 1):

Наример так:

```js
var str = 'текст. текст. текст';

str = str.replace(/(^|\.\s+)(.)/g, function(a, b, c){
  return b + c.toUpperCase();
});

console.log( str );
```

Где параметр `a` у функции является полным найденным совпадением по регулярке, `b` - найденное совпадение внутри первых скобок, `c` - найденное совпадение внутри вторых скобок.

b == (^|\.\s+) == Начало строки `^`, или `|`, точка с одним или несколькими пробелами `\.\s+` 

с == любой найденный символ `(.)` (не сиська)